# easy_install is different for python2 and python3 or not?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, setuptools, easy-install

I had installed easy_install using `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`. Will it install easy_install for python2 or python3?
I want to install `virtualenv` using `sudo easy_install virtualenv`. So, will virtualenv python interpreter will depends on easy_install python interpreter ? Or I can run virtualenv for any python interpreter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

installs `setuptools` for Python 2. For Python 3 the command is

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

As for `virtualenv` — you can install it for one Python but use with any:

```
virtualenv --python python3.4
```

even if `virtualenv` is for Python 2.7 or 3.6.